# Redirect to another page in React in 3 seconds, not working

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-router, react-router-dom

```
export default function Home() {
  const [redirect, setRedirect] = useState<boolean>(false);
  const [redirecting, setRedirecting] = useState<boolean>(false);

  const userContext = useContext(UserContext);

  useEffect(() => {
    const value: string | null = localStorage.getItem("user");
    if (!value) {
      return setRedirecting(true);
    }
    const user: User = JSON.parse(value ?? "");

    if (userContext) {
      userContext.setUser({
        ...user,
      });
    }
  }, [userContext]);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (redirecting) {
      setTimeout(() => {
        console.log("here 1")
        setRedirect(true)
      }, 3000);
    }
  }, [redirecting]);

  if (redirecting || !userContext?.user) {
    return (
      <Container sx={{ my: 2 }}>
        <Typography variant="h5">
          You need to register to access this page.
        </Typography>
      </Container>
    );
  }
  if (redirect) {
    console.log("here 2");
    return <Navigate to={"/register"} />
  }

  return (
    <div>Home Content</div>
  );
}
```

The value of `redirect` does get changed, but somehow the code responsible to navigate is not executing.

Comment: Instead of ```.....```, you could give some debugging details. Like Does console log ```here 2``` is executed? Does the url change? From where you import ```Navigate``` and which version is that library? Are there any errors in the console? How many times the first ```useEffect``` gets called, seems like an infinite loop to me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you set `redirect` to `true` the `redirecting` is still `true`, therefore the first condition is true and the first return is the one executing.

You should change the logic of the return

```js
return (
  <>
    {redirect && <Navigate to={"/register"} />}
    <Container sx={{ my: 2 }}>
      <Typography variant="h5">
        You need to register to access this page.
      </Typography>
    </Container>
  </>
);
```

Answer (score 0):

first of all simplify your code, also use react best practices. it will help you to debug code easily. something like below.

```
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";

export default function Home() {


  const navigate = useNavigate();
  const userContext = useContext(UserContext);

  useEffect(() => {
    const value: string | null = localStorage.getItem("user");
    if (!value) {
      navigate("/register");
    } else {

      const user: User = JSON.parse(value ?? "");

      if (userContext) {
        userContext.setUser({
          ...user,
        });
      }
    }
  }, [userContext]);


  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      {
        !userContext?.user
          ? <Container sx={{ my: 2 }}>
            <Typography variant="h5">
              You need to register to access this page.
            </Typography>
          </Container>
          : <div>Home Content</div>
      }
    </React.Fragment>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `Home` component is doing too much ***unrelated*** work, it should only be concerned with rendering home page content. There is no clear separations of concerns and the result is needlessly convoluted code.

If you need to load user data from localStorage, *do that in the `UserContext` context provider*.

Example:

```
const UserContext = React.createContext({
  user,
  setUser,
});

const useUserContext = React.useContext(UserContext);

const UserContextProvider = ({ children }) => {
  // Initialize from localStorage
  const [user, setUser] = React.useState(() => {
    return JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("user")) as User;
  });

  return (
    <UserContext.Provider value={{ user, setUser }}>
      {children}
    </UserContext>
  );
};
```

If you need to protect access to routes,  *create a `ProtectedRoutes` component and do this in the router/routes*.

Example:

```
import { Navigate, Outlet, useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';

const ProtectedRoutes = () => {
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  const { user } = useUserContext();

  React.useEffect(() => {
    if (!user) {
      // Redirect to login page in 3 seconds
      const timer = setTimeout(navigate, 3000, "/login", { replace: true });

      // Cleanup function to clear timer in case user navigates away early
      return () => {
        clearTimeout(timer);
      };
    }
  }, []);

  return user
    {/* Authenticated users see protected route content */}
    ? <Outlet />
    {/* Unauthenticated users UI */}
    : (
      <Container sx={{ my: 2 }}>
        <Typography variant="h5">
          You need to register to access this page.
        </Typography>
      </Container>
    );
};
```

```
<Routes>
  {/* Routes that are protected from unauthenticated users */}
  <Route element={<ProtectedRoutes />}>
    <Route path="/home" element={<Home />} />
    ...
  </Route>

  {/* Unprotected routes that are any users can access */}
  ...
</Routes>
```

The `Home` component should just render home content.

```
export default function Home() {
  return (
    <div>Home Content</div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for this descriptive reply. Actually, I am a beginner just starting out with React that's why I was not aware, that something like protected routes also exists.